# establish if there is a linear application $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\ker(\varphi) = V$ and $\operatorname{im}(\varphi) = W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given the subspace in $\mathbb{R}^3$

$ V = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x+y+z = 0\} $ and $W = \operatorname{span}\{(2, -1, 2)\}$.

I have to establish if there is a linear application $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\ker(\varphi) = V$ and $\operatorname{im}(\varphi) = W$. If it exists, give an example

First of all I find a base of V: $B_v = \{(-1, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 1)\}$.

There is a linear application that satisfies the conditions because: $\dim(\mathbb{R}^3) = \dim(\ker(\varphi))+ \dim(\operatorname{im}(\varphi)) \implies 3 = 2 +1$

But now I don't know how to find an explicit linear application.

Comment: Find two vectors in the subspace $V$ that are linearly independent, and assign $\phi(v)=0$ for both of them. Then find any vector not in the subspace and define $\phi(u)=(2,-1,2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This case is one of those in which you can take a shortcut and just write:

$$\varphi(x,y,z)=(x+y+z)(2, -1, 2)=(2x+2y+2z, -x-y-z, 2x+2y+2z)$$

Can you now prove that $\ker(\varphi)=V$ and $\text{im}(\varphi)=W$?

Comment: I have to check if these conditions are met: $\varphi(-1, -1, 0)=(0, 0, 0)$, $\varphi(-1, 0, 1)=(0, 0, 0)$ and if $\varphi(2, -1, 2)= span(w)$

Comment: Sort of. For $\ker\varphi$ it is actually easier: $(x,y,z)\in\ker\varphi\Leftrightarrow(x+y+z)(2,-1,2)=(0,0,0)\Leftrightarrow x+y+z=0\Leftrightarrow (x,y,z)\in V$. For $\text{im}\varphi=W$ you can easily see that $\text{im}\varphi\subseteq W$, and for any $(2\lambda, -\lambda, 2\lambda)\in W$, you have $\varphi(\lambda, 0, 0)=(2\lambda, -\lambda, 2\lambda)$ which gives you the opposite inclusion. .

Comment: My point is - in this problem you don't necessarily need to find the basis of $V$ - although, certainly, you can also do it your way. (However, if you went down that route, I hope you would be able to work out all the details. For example, strictly speaking, $\varphi(-1, -1, 0)=(0,0,0)$, $\varphi(-1, 0, 1)=(0,0,0)$ only proves that $V\subseteq \ker\varphi$ - why is the opposite inclusion true?)

Comment: maybe I didn't understand the question, isn't it because in the text we have established that $\ker(\varphi)=V$

Comment: In which text? Certainly not in the text of your question, because you don't have $\varphi$ defined there (in fact, the question *is* to find it!), and certainly not in the text of my answer, as my answer is just writing down what $\varphi$ *can* be, and leaving it to you to prove that it is satisfying the conditions from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Let the normal vector of $V$ be $a$ (e.g. $a = (1,1,1)$). Then, $\varphi$ must be non-zero only in $\text{span}\{a\}$. This means that $\varphi$ must be of the form
$$\varphi(x) = (ba^\top) x.$$
Now, we want the image of $\varphi$ to be $\text{span}(w)$. Then, we just set $b=w$ and we're done.